# SQL Server 2008 WHERE clause with CASE / WHEN and NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, null, case

I'm trying to write something like :

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable m
WHERE m.Category = CASE WHEN @Category IS NULL THEN m.Category ELSE @Category END
```

Basically, I need lines where `m.Category` equals `@Category` if this one has a value ; else, I need all lines.

BUT if `m.Category` has `NULL` value, the line is NOT send back because SQL needs something lile `WHERE m.Category IS NULL` and not `WHERE m.Category = NULL`.

So, how could I modify my request to tell to SQL : "I need ALL lines if `@Category` is null (even lines where `m.Category` is null), but if `@Category` has a value, I just need lines where `m.Category` matches `@Category` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write it like this:

```
select *
from MyTable m
where @Category is null or m.Category = @Category
```

Comment: Ok, it was so easy I didn't even think about it... Thanks a lot

Comment: @roman-pekar - what do you call this?  I used it about 5 years ago and had the need for it today and I couldn't for the life of me remember what it is called.

Comment: @Steven well I don't know, not sure it has some specific name